# Reporting framework with edit support

Tags: .net, sdk, report, reporting

I'm evaluating reporting solutions for an upcoming project, to allow report generation from training sessions.
There are some charts and tables required in each report, but nothing too special. The only issue is that the software should allow editing reports in the "preview" screen. There should be dedicated controls after each chart/table to edit text.

The basic workflow is as follows:

- Generate a report preview for a certain training session (includes charts, tables, etc.)
- Add/edit/remove comments after charts, add/edit grades, etc.
- Save the report and export to PDF and excel

The user-inserted data (comments, etc.) should be saved in the database for future report generation of the same session.

Is there a reporting framework (preferably for .NET) that supports modifying data as described above? Currently it seems like my only option is to go for a homemade solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[myDBR](http://mydbr.com) allows data editing directly within the report. You can control the access to the editing features via normal user privileges.